# C++ if....else if..else?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to use if/ else if/ else statements in my code but I do not know why it will not work. I have a character variable called "type_of_clothes" and I ask the user to input their option of what type of clothes they would like. "P or p" for pants, "S or s" for shirts, and "SH or sh" for shorts. Whenever the input P||p the program runs just fine, but whenever I input S||s the program does not follow what I have set in case the user inputs S||s. I used if / else if/ if, but it will not work. Is there is something that I am missing? Thank you for your time. Any other suggestions to improve my code are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double waistMeasure (double a) {
    double x;

    x = a *1.5;
    return ( x );
}

double heightMeasure (double a) {
    double x;

    x = a * 0.4444444444;
    return ( x );
    }

double pleadedPants(double a) {
    double x;

    x = a * 0.1;
    return ( x );
}

double baggyPants (double a, double b, double c) {
    double x;

    x = (a + b + c) * 0.15;
    return ( x );
}

double shirtWaistMeasure (double a) {
    double x;

    x = a * 0.66666667;
    return ( x );
}

double shirtHeightMeasure (double a) {
    double x;

    x = a * 3.375;
    return ( x );
}

double longSleeveShirt (double a ) {
    double x;

    x = a * 1.5;
    return ( x );
}

int main ()
{
    char type_of_clothes, pleaded_op, baggy_op, longSleeve_Op;
    double waistSize, heightSize, total_shirt_cloth, shirt_waist_size, shirt_height_size, arm_length;
    double total_Cloth = 0.00; 

    cout << "What do you want, [P]ants or [S]hirts or [SH]orts?: " << endl;
    cin >> type_of_clothes;

    if ( type_of_clothes == 'P'|| 'P') {
        cout << "Give me your waist size in inches:  " << endl;
        cin >> waistSize;
        cout << waistMeasure(waistSize) << endl;

        cout << "Give me your height size in inches:  " << endl;
        cin >> heightSize;
        cout << heightMeasure(heightSize) << endl;

        cout << "Pleaded front? [Y / N]:  " << endl;
        cin >> pleaded_op;

        total_Cloth = waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize);

        if (pleaded_op == 'Y'|| 'y') {
            pleadedPants(waistSize);

            cout << pleadedPants(waistSize) << endl;

            total_Cloth = waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize) + pleadedPants (waistSize);
        }

        else if( pleaded_op == 'N'||'n' ) {
            cout << "No pleaded shirt." << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Baggylook? [Y / N]:  " << endl;
        cin >> baggy_op;

        if ( baggy_op == 'Y'||'y' ) {
            baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize) );
            cout << baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize) ) << endl;

            total_Cloth = baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize)) + waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize) + pleadedPants (waistSize);
        }

        else if ( baggy_op == 'N'||'n' ) {
            cout << "No baggy style." << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input! Try again." << endl;
        }

        cout << total_Cloth << endl;
    }

    else if ( type_of_clothes == 'S'||'s' ) {
        cout << "Give me your waist size:  " << endl;
        cin >> shirt_waist_size;
        cout << shirtWaistMeasure( shirt_waist_size);

        cout << "Give me your height:  " << endl;
        cin >> shirt_height_size;
        cout << shirtHeightMeasure( shirt_height_size );

        total_shirt_cloth = shirtWaistMeasure(shirt_waist_size) + shirtHeightMeasure (shirt_height_size);


        cout << "Would you like long sleeves? [ Y =  YES/ N = NO ]:  " << endl;
        cin >> longSleeve_Op;

        if ( longSleeve_Op = 'Y'||'y') {
            cout << "Give me your arms length:  " << endl;
            cin >> arm_length;
            longSleeveShirt(arm_length);
            cout << longSleeveShirt(arm_length);

            total_shirt_cloth = shirtWaistMeasure(shirt_waist_size) + shirtHeightMeasure(shirt_height_size) + longSleeveShirt (arm_length);
        }

        else if ( longSleeve_Op == 'N'||'n' ) {
            cout << "No long sleeve shirt." <<endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input. Try again." << endl;
        }
    }

    else {
        cout<< "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (pleaded_op == 'Y'|| 'y')
```

doesn't do what you expect. You must test separately

```
if (pleaded_op == 'Y' || pleaded_op == 'y')
```

Comment: You can reduce to 1 compare by using `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`. By using one of these first, you can then use a `switch` statement instead of the `if-else if` ladder.'

Comment: agreed, but since the OP didn't know how the || operator worked that seemed like a more important first lesson.

Answer (score 0):

this:
( type_of_clothes == 'P'|| 'P')
Totally invalid.
You need something like this:

```
if ( a == b )
{
     if( b == c )
     {
          ...
     }
     ...
}
```

or something like that: 
if ( ( a == b ) && ( a != c ) )
{
     ...
}

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The programming language is different how you read or speak english.

*If type_of_clothes equals to 'P' or 'p' then do something...* will be written in C++ like the following:

```
if(type_of_clothes == 'p'|| type_of_clothes == 'P')
{
    //do something...
```

**Improvement:** In your code, all the functions `waistMeasure`, `heightMeasure` etc. can be changed to

```
double waistMeasure(double a) {
    return a *1.5;
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't do if(a == 'this' || 'this'), you have to use your char on both sides.

As a secondary note, you can wrap this in a whileloop to continue operations after your if statement has finished.

Example (I didn't fix all your issues, only the top one. use it to fix the others):

```
while(1) //while running
{
    cout << "What do you want, [P]ants or [S]hirts or [SH]orts?: " << endl;
    cin >> type_of_clothes;
    //see how i have put the char on both sides?
    if (type_of_clothes == 'P' || type_of_clothes == 'p') {

        cout << "Give me your waist size in inches:  " << endl;
        cin >> waistSize;
        cout << waistMeasure(waistSize) << endl;

        cout << "Give me your height size in inches:  " << endl;
        cin >> heightSize;
        cout << heightMeasure(heightSize) << endl;

        cout << "Pleaded front? [Y / N]:  " << endl;
        cin >> pleaded_op;

        total_Cloth = waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize);

        if (pleaded_op == 'Y' || 'y') {

            pleadedPants(waistSize);

            cout << pleadedPants(waistSize) << endl;

            total_Cloth = waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize) + pleadedPants(waistSize);
        }

        else if (pleaded_op == 'N' || 'n') {

            cout << "No pleaded shirt." << endl;

        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        }


        cout << "Baggylook? [Y / N]:  " << endl;
        cin >> baggy_op;

        if (baggy_op == 'Y' || 'y') {

            baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize));
            cout << baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize)) << endl;

            total_Cloth = baggyPants(waistMeasure(waistSize), heightMeasure(heightSize), pleadedPants(waistSize)) + waistMeasure(waistSize) + heightMeasure(heightSize) + pleadedPants(waistSize);
        }

        else if (baggy_op == 'N' || 'n') {

            cout << "No baggy style." << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input! Try again." << endl;
        }


        cout << total_Cloth << endl;

    }



    else if (type_of_clothes == 'S' || 's') {

        cout << "Give me your waist size:  " << endl;
        cin >> shirt_waist_size;
        cout << shirtWaistMeasure(shirt_waist_size);

        cout << "Give me your height:  " << endl;
        cin >> shirt_height_size;
        cout << shirtHeightMeasure(shirt_height_size);

        total_shirt_cloth = shirtWaistMeasure(shirt_waist_size) + shirtHeightMeasure(shirt_height_size);


        cout << "Would you like long sleeves? [ Y =  YES/ N = NO ]:  " << endl;
        cin >> longSleeve_Op;

        if (longSleeve_Op = 'Y' || 'y') {

            cout << "Give me your arms length:  " << endl;
            cin >> arm_length;
            longSleeveShirt(arm_length);
            cout << longSleeveShirt(arm_length);

            total_shirt_cloth = shirtWaistMeasure(shirt_waist_size) + shirtHeightMeasure(shirt_height_size) + longSleeveShirt(arm_length);
        }

        else if (longSleeve_Op == 'N' || 'n') {

            cout << "No long sleeve shirt." << endl;

        }

        else {

            cout << "Invalid input. Try again." << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you can't test this entire block at once.

```
if ( baggy_op == 'Y'||'y' )
```

Instead, it should be divided into two components like this.

```
if (baggy_op == 'Y'|| baggy_op == 'y')
```

Also, please indent your code better, it helps a great deal to be able to read it easier.